# How to log peak commit charge for a system

Tags: c#, .net, memory, wmi

Are there any classes in WMI that can help me extract the Peak Memory Commit Charge for a system?  The value can be viewed in Task Manager/"Commit Charge (K)"/"Peak", however, I would like to be able to export this value programatically using .NET.

Comment: Other related values can be read from Performance Counters. However, it looks like there isn't one for this particular value, so I don't know how you'd get it. Here's a page that lists some related counters, in case it's helpful: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958260.aspx

Comment: Ya I went down that road already, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Going to post Nate C-K's answer as Community Wiki.

There is no performance counter corresponding to the Peak Commit Charge figure. There is a table [on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958260.aspx) confirming that no counter exists that corresponds to this metric.

So the only way you can log it is to query the number using `NtQuerySystemInformation`. A [PowerShell sample](http://blog.whatsupduck.net/2010/05/querying-peak-commit-bytes-with.html) is available. You could even expose it as a [performance counter of your own](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/how-do-i-publish-a-custom-application-performance-counter-in-c/), which can then be consumed like any other performance counter.